# Still getting "mapped items should have keys" warning even when keys are present

Tags: reactjs

I have the following functional component. It basically maps over an array of objects, and returns a datalist full of options:

```
const Suggestions = (props) => {
    if(props.suggestions){    
        let data = props.suggestions.map(r => (
          <React.Fragment>
          {r.bar ? <option key={r.index} value={r.bar.toUpperCase()/> : null}
          {r.shop ? <option key={r.index} value={r.shop.toUpperCase()/> : null}
             </React.Fragment>
        ));

        return <datalist id="places">{data}</datalist>
    }
    return null
}
```

I still get the following warning on the console:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Suggestions`.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a `key` property on the objects contained in `suggestions`? That's what the error is asking for, not that the `option` element itself has a `key` attribute.

Comment: No, there isn´t. But I thought the key was made during the map by the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) should go on the root element being rendered in a loop. In your case, it's the `React.Fragment`. Also, ensure the `key` is unique among all siblings in a loop:

```
let data = props.suggestions.map((r, index) => (
  <React.Fragment key={index}>
    {r.bar ? <option value={r.bar.toUpperCase()/> : null}
    {r.shop ? <option value={r.shop.toUpperCase()/> : null}
  </React.Fragment>
));
```

Comment: Keys also must be unique. What are the values of `r.index`? You could instead use the index of the suggestion in the loop. I'll update my code with a suggestion.

Comment: Updated the code to use the index of the iteration in the loop. If there is a better way to uniquely identify a `suggestion`, you should use that. Does a `suggestion` have an `id`? What does a `suggestion` look like?

Comment: No, that´s the only feasible way (no unique values in the array). Thanks!